# how to create back button in navigation bar in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments

I want to create a back navigation button that will take me back to the fragment before it when pressed. I looked at so many questions asked here but none of them help my needs. If anyone here know something or have an idea on how to do this please direct me or at least show me how to do it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post some code, please? Are you using Toolbar or old ActionBar?

Comment: thanks @Jerry I am using toolbar. All I need is some information on how to do it

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534381/toolbar-add-the-up-button) might help you. Good luck!

Comment: thank dude I would up vote but I cant it seems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to use a toolbar in the activity. I think that will depend on which theme you use.

```
@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light
```

Will give you a toolbar.

Then you set up the button in onCreate in your activity:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And last you set an action when you click on that back-button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      onBackPressed();
      return true;
  }

  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It is the `onBackPressed()` that return you back to the previous activity.